# Image disappear on rotation in Processing

Tags: java, image, rotation, transformation, processing

I'm using the [Processing](http://processing.org) language to do a little game, but I'm having trouble with images and rotation. My sprite displays fine if I apply no rotation to it, but it disappears completely if it is rotated. Here's the rotation code:

```
void display(boolean alternate) {
    pushMatrix();
    if(!isHead && !isTail && alternate) rotate(radians(180));
    rotate(radians(90*direction));
    image(snake, x, y, linkSize, linkSize);
    popMatrix();
}
```

When `direction` is 0, or `alternate` is true and `direction` is 2, then the image displays. Otherwise, no image is displayed. I'm not sure if it matters or not, but snake is a .png image with an alpha transparency. The declaration for snake is `snake = loadImage("SnakeLink.png");`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually rotating the image from it's origin (top left corner), so it disappears from the screen.
You have to translate to the center of the image, rotate, translate back to it's origin and then display it.

```
translate(image.width/2, image.height/2);
rotate(radians);
translate(-image.width/2, -image.height/2);
```

Comment: So, if I'm trying to put the top left corner of the image at coordinates (x,y) in the window, do I do this, then draw the image at x,y?

Comment: You can draw at x,y or translate(x,y) and just draw. Translate moves the origin, the whole world. To properly rotate an object around it's center, you have to translate the world to the center, rotate it, then translate back.